# How to redirect page with Javascript in React-Router?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I using `react-router` in my application.

In my login page, I needing authentication with `ajax` and redirect if success.

Some like following code:

```
class PageLogin extends React.Component {
    login() {
        // How to can I redirect to another page if auth success?
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="login-page">
                <form action="">
                    <div className="form-group">
                        <label>Username:</label>
                        <input type="text"/>
                    </div>
                    <div className="form-group">
                        <label>Password:</label>
                        <input type="text"/>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <button onClick={this.login}>Login</button>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

In my `login` function, how to can I redirect to another page if authentication success?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Context is the best option, however official documentation tells that you can also use [`withRouter`](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/withRouter) to put `router` prop to your component that would correctly perform history state transition:

```
import { withRouter } from 'react-router';

class PageLogin extends React.Component {
    login() {
        this.props.history.push('/some/location'); // for react-router@3 it would be this.props.router.push('/some/location');
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="login-page">
                <form action="">
                    <div className="form-group">
                        <label>Username:</label>
                        <input type="text"/>
                    </div>
                    <div className="form-group">
                        <label>Password:</label>
                        <input type="text"/>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <button onClick={this.login}>Login</button>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default withRouter(PageLogin);
```

Comment: bravvoo..!! exactly what i was looking for Thanks a lot!!

Comment: link is 404, think new location is https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Router

Comment: for v.4.2.0 it is:
this.props.history.push('/');

Comment: Doug & Konstantin, thanks, folks! The link and the reference property in the example are now updated.

Answer (score 1):

You'll have a reference to the Router in context. [You can simply call `router.push` with your new path to redirect](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/docs/API.md#pushpathorloc).

```
class PageLogin extends React.Component {
  login() {
    this.context.router.push('/newPath');
  }
  ...
 }

PageLogin.contextTypes = {
  router: React.PropTypes.object
}
```

If you don't want to push a route to their history, but instead replace their current route, you can [call `replace` instead](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/docs/API.md#replacepathorloc). The API is identical to `push`.

Comment: This is not the current API of React Router.. the selected best answer is the correct usage now.